# Is the software used in the "seabed UFO" video GIS software? If so, what is it?

Tags: software-recommendations

The icons almost make it look like the software is ArcReader or an ArcEngine based, but it's hard to tell from the video.  I supposed it could not be GIS software at all.

Is anyone familiar with this software?

Here's the video link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwHE5816_XY&feature=player_embedded#t=56s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is [SonarWave Lite](http://blogs.tekmap.ns.ca/archives/category/sonar_wave_lite) by Tekmap. It's free and can be downloaded from the preceding link if you have some SONAR data lying around that you want to play with.

The company who makes it also appears to make heavy use of GRASS and GDAL - so you can consider SonarWave Lite to be GIS-based, but for a very specific application.

EDIT: I looked a bit more into this and found some [open-source software](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/pi/MB-System/) for SONAR analysis.

EDIT 2: [Here](http://searchforamelia.org/sonar-data) is a link to some free marine SONAR data if you want to play around with it using the above tools.

Comment: This looks cool -- you should post it in this thread: [GIS Pros - What free programs should every GIS user have installed?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/gis-pros-what-free-programs-should-every-gis-user-have-installed)

Comment: @Radar: That is cool...you should change your user name to Sonar!

Comment: @Jay - If I could get some more SONAR experience that might be a good idea! I've found it to be difficult to come across free data online. If anyone has some sources feel free to add them to this thread.

Comment: Good eye! Now what about that anomaly in the image?

Comment: @Kirk It's clearly the Millennium Falcon.